# Dockerfile - Copying config files to appropriate container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, amazon-ecs, supervisord

I have two containers on my deployment: `uwsgi` and `celery`. There are also two `supervisord` `.conf` files, under `/config/celery` and `/config/uwsgi`. So I need to copy only the `*.conf` files under `/config/celery` to `/etc/supervisor` directory in the `celery` container and only the `*.conf` files under `/config/uwsgi` to `/etc/supervisor` in the `uwsgi` container.
I'm using AWS's `ECS` to deploy the containers.

Beforehand, when I had a single `supervisord.conf` file I could do as following in my `Dockerfile`:

`COPY ./config/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor`

and that would work. The point now is I have multiple `supervisord.conf` that needs to be copied to the appropriate container, based on its name.
The entrypoint of both containers is

`supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: You can use args to pass the arguments to the docker file and based the arguments COPY the supervisord.conf. I used to use to pass in my docker-compose either dev or prod give the environment.

Comment: @juliansalas the deployment is at AWS ECS, as mentioned ... not at a docker-compose. But could you elaborate more?

Comment: I’d build two separate images, and not use supervisord in either.

Comment: @DavidMaze could you please elaborate more? Would you use systemctl or service to start the processes?

Comment: No, neither; I’d just start them with something like `CMD uwsgi ...`.  (To a first approximation neither `systemctl` nor `service` work at all in Docker.)